# C# ReportViewer - different layout for xls

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I was wondering if it would be possible to use a different layout for 'export als xls'. The reason for this is that what looks nice (ie visible raport, pdf and word) is sometimes very different to what is practical in excel. I've tried looking through the documentation, to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I agree on the export.  As Excel or Word does nothing but "objects" with explicit placement and nothing really practical to work with.  I actually wrote my own hook on the export action to just grab the data from the report context and dump it directly in a format I wanted.

Now note... what I have here is a snippet of code from my Main Report Manager.  From which all my reports are derived so I don't have to write the same reporting preview framework over and over.  In my class, I have a virtual method GenerateData() and each subclassed report does its own thing to query the database, prepare the data table and then add the data table to a "DataSet" on the main report and let the report continue.

The export option also is a virtual function that each subclassed report knows what it's own data table is and may have some restriction(s) on what columns are exported and then call the method TableToCSV() for the final export.

Hope this gives you some ideas for your needs.

```
// hook for when exporting is done.
reportViewer.ReportExport += reportViewer_ReportExport;


void reportViewer_ReportExport(object sender, ReportExportEventArgs e)
{
    // Prepare an Export path for the user's desktop
    exportPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            + "\\SomeExportPath\\";

    // In case multiple exports, time-stamp the file name too
    timeMark = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss");

    if (sender != null )
    {
        switch( e.Extension.Name )
        {
            case "Excel":
                ExportForExcel();
                e.Cancel = true;
                Messagebox( "Exported Excel(CSV) to your desktop in the \r\n"
                        + "folder 'SomeExportPath\\SomeFile.csv'" ); 
                break;
        }
    }
}

protected virtual void ExportForExcel()
{}

protected void TableToCSV( DataTable dt, string FinalFileName )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => 
          string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
    }
    File.WriteAllText(exportPath + FinalFileName + ".csv", sb.ToString());

}
```